# Change Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]
[image]r.png
                                                                                 I want to take navigation drawer in right side of activity. when i click on list recycle list item (not navigation drawer item) and open fragment in activity, that time drawer move to right to left.

thank you.

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain what you're trying to do a little more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Gravity to Right using

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

As well as

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close) {

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Good luck.